# Placing the current location and another location in MKMapKit......

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

**Query 1:**
I'm using MKMapKit in which I want to display two location one is current location and another is a fixed location I use this code...

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,46,320,370)];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:TRUE];    
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.9;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.9;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location=mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    location.latitude=13.160407;
    location.longitude=80.249562;
    region.span=span;
    region.center=location;
    geoCoder =[[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate] autorelease];
    geoCoder.delegate = self;
    [geoCoder start];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)MapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
 NSLog(@"View for Annotation is called");

if (NSClassFromString(@"MKUserLocation")==[annotation class]) {
    return nil;
}
MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn;
annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;

annView.canShowCallout = YES;
annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
pindropped = TRUE;
//[map addAnnotations:annotation];
return annView;}
```

I Know this question has been posted many times,but I can't find any solution for my issue.......

**Query 2:**
I need to plot the way between two locations in MPMapKit(as in google maps),How can I do tis???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: You forgot your problem ;-) i assume, you don't see your location...
there are two ways: 
mapview can show your location ->

`mapView.showsUserLocation = YES`

or you add a Annotation to the mapView :

`[mapview addAnnotation:myLocation]`

but please read the docs for mkmapview, your implementation is incomplete (missing delegates)
and take a look at the examples

2: not as easy as on google maps javascript api. you have to draw lines from point to point. therefore you need the exact route from google.

Comment: No I can See the current location (from simulator) the blue dot I can't find the fixed location (i ve mentioned some of the coordinates in my code)

Comment: you never add the fixed location to the map. make an annotation with the location and add it to the mapView